# Loop through With query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, with-statement

I have a query like below:

```
with srcpersons as 
(select personid,
        personname,
        personbirth,
        personno
    From personstable), 
    persondetails as 
            (select personid,
                    personname,
                    personbirth,
                    personno,
                    recdate = GETDATE,
                    batchid = 1
            from srcpersons
            where personid > 1)

 select personid,
        personname,
        personbirth,
        personno,
        recdate,
        batchid
into #persondetails
from persondetails
```

Can I use the #persondetails with a loop?

I mean something like this:

```
        -----
        -----
        into #persondetails
        from persondetails
        Begin
           WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
             BEGIN
                ---
                ---
             End
        End
```

I have many procedures which are using With query, and they use insert statement to tables inside the With query, but I need to do some process with the records before the insertion.

I mean, I need to go to through the records within the With query(srcpersons) or the temp table(#persondetails) one by one before the insertion.

Comment: Look at Cursors?

Comment: Although you could declare a cursor for the `WITH` statement (common table expression) for RBAR processing, it is generally best to use a set-based operation in SQL Server. But without knowing what you are doing inside the loop that transforms rows one at a time, we cannot offer suggestions.

Comment: A [Cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples) could do that, but in 99% of the cases where a cursor is used this can be replaced by a single query which will perform many many many times better. If you would explain what you want to do in the cursor me might help you with this

Comment: It's highly unlikely you actually need any kind of loop, but without context it's hard to say

Comment: My aim is, when I have many records which need to be updated in one of the tables, and if one of these records has an issue,  like (miss match data type, miss match length, null value ..) with the single query I can not get which record has the issue, then I can report it to be fixed!
But what will happen is, if there is an error, the query will be terminated, and will not declare which record has the issue! 
In addition, I need to find a solution to make the query to be continue with the correct records and exclude the fault record if there is, but not terminated at all!